# Excel Hyperlink Function, getting "Cannot open the specified file" when trying to use website hyperlinks

Tags: excel, hyperlink, office365

Ok so I was hoping i would be able to use the Hyperlink() function in excel to take links to tickets at work and give them a more "Simplified" name to the hyperlink, currently I have cell B6 as the friendly name i want to use and cell C6 as the ticket link. My formula looks like this:

```
=HYPERLINK(Misc!C6,Misc!B6)
```

the data I have in B6 is "Example Ticket"

the data I have in C6 is "www.google.com"

and I have D6 as the cell with the formula

[Cell Formatting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iRPeP.png)

it does output what I expect which is a new link to google.com labelled as "Example Ticket" however when I click that link it shows a warning saying "Cannot open the specified file" I have verified that the link I have in C6 opens up google.com when I click it but when I click the new link it creates it just shows that warning.

I have tried using different links for this, including google.com, https://www.google.com/, [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) but none of these work, ive also tried having the formula formatted in different ways but either they just create the same link that gives me that error or they dont work altogether

```
=HYPERLINK(Misc!C6,Misc!B6)

=HYPERLINK(#Misc!C6,#Misc!B6)

=HYPERLINK(C6,B6)
```

I'm not sure if you able to use this function to create links like this but I thought I'd ask to see if anyone has encountered this or would know :)

Steps to Reproduce:

1. Enter "Example Ticket" into cell B6
2. Enter "www.google.com" into cell C6
3. Enter the formula "=HYPERLINK(Misc!C6,Misc!B6)" into cell D6
4. Press Enter
5. Click the new link in D6

**Expected Results:**

the link opens google.com

**Actual Results:**

error message Cannot open the specified file is shown

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wzfPi.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was successful after setting the C6 value to
http://www.google.com/
All others resulted in the error you described.  So, consider using this for your url  http://www.google.com/   The trailing slash seems to make all the difference.

Comment: Thanks man, that worked!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use this website

```
https://www.google.com
```